# Помогите написать функцию, добавляющую строку двухмерному массиву в указанную позицию

Tags: c++, visual-c++

У меня пока получилось только добавить строку в конец массива. Я пока не знаю как можно доработать код чтобы можно было добавить строку заполненую нолями в другую позицию.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Вывод динамического массива
void print(int** katalog, int stroki, int stolbci) {
    
    cout << "Array of arrays (" << stroki << " x " << stolbci << "):" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < stroki; i++) {
        
        for (int j = 0; j < stolbci; j++) {
            
            cout << katalog[i][j] << " ";
            
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
}
void add_stroki(int** &katalog, int &stroki, int stolbci) {
    int* newmass = new int [stolbci] {}; 
    int** new_katalog = new int* [stroki + 1]{};
    for (int i = 0; i < stroki; i++) new_katalog[i] = katalog[i];
    new_katalog[stroki] = newmass;
    delete[] katalog;
        katalog = new_katalog;
        stroki++;

}
int main()
{
    


    // А теперь сделаем этот список массивов динамическим, его адрес поместим в указатель.
    // Указатель на первый элемент массива, в котором элементами являются указатели.
    // То есть, указатель на указатель.
    int** massiv_massivov; // указатель на int*



    int row_count = 5;
    int column_count =10 ;
    // Создаем массив из пяти указателей 
    massiv_massivov = new int* [row_count]; // пять указателей на int, то есть пять int*, пока они ни на что не указывают



    // создадим пять динамических массивов, в каждом по 10 чисел
    for (int i = 0; i < row_count; i++)
        massiv_massivov[i] = new int[column_count];



    // работаем как с обычным двумерным массивом 5 x 10
    // заполняем
    int val = 123;
    for (int i = 0; i < row_count; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column_count; j++) {
            massiv_massivov[i][j] = val;
            val++;
        }
    }


    
    // выводим
    print(massiv_massivov, row_count, column_count);
    add_stroki(massiv_massivov, row_count, column_count);
    print(massiv_massivov, row_count, column_count);


    // освобождаем память
    // Сначала удаляем 5 массивов, потом удаляем массив, в котором лежали их адреса.
    for (int i = 0; i < row_count; i++)
        delete[] massiv_massivov[i];
    delete[] massiv_massivov;
}
```

Comment: То есть у вас есть индекс, по которому нужно создать новую строку и вставить на место и массив при этом увеличивается на одну строку? Или просто в указанной индексом строке всё заменить на 0?

Comment: да массив увеличится на одну строк узаполненную нолями

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так, с соблюдением авторского стиля именования переменных и функций:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

// Вывод динамического массива
void print(int** katalog, int stroki, int stolbci) {
  cout << "Array of arrays (" << stroki << " x " << stolbci << "):" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < stroki; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < stolbci; j++)
      cout << setw(3) << katalog[i][j] << " ";
    cout << endl;
  }
}

// Вставка строки
void add_stroki(int**& katalog, int& stroki, int stolbci, int pos) {
  katalog = (int**) realloc(katalog, sizeof(int*) * (++stroki));
  memmove(katalog + pos + 1, katalog + pos, sizeof(int*) * (stroki - pos));
  katalog[pos] = (int*)calloc(stolbci, sizeof(int));
}

int main() {
  // А теперь сделаем этот список массивов динамическим, его адрес поместим в указатель.
  // Указатель на первый элемент массива, в котором элементами являются указатели.
  // То есть, указатель на указатель.
  int** massiv_massivov; // указатель на int*
  int row_count = 5;
  int column_count = 10;
  // Создаем массив из пяти указателей
  // Пять указателей на int, то есть пять int*, пока они ни на что не указывают
  massiv_massivov = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*)*row_count);  
  // Создадим пять динамических массивов, в каждом по 10 чисел
  for (int i = 0; i < row_count; i++) massiv_massivov[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
  // работаем как с обычным двумерным массивом 5 x 10
  // заполняем
  int val = 123;
  for (int i = 0; i < row_count; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < column_count; j++) {
      massiv_massivov[i][j] = val;
      val++;
    }
  }
  // выводим
  print(massiv_massivov, row_count, column_count);
  // вставляем в позицию 2, отсчет от нуля
  add_stroki(massiv_massivov, row_count, column_count, 2);
  print(massiv_massivov, row_count, column_count);
  // освобождаем память
  // Сначала удаляем 6 массивов, потом удаляем массив, в котором лежали их адреса.
  for (int i = 0; i < row_count; i++) free(massiv_massivov[i]);
  free(massiv_massivov);
}
```

[Онлайн тут](https://ideone.com/YeJ4dW).

PS. Проверки не вставлял, корректность индексов на совести ТС.